# Get checked items from ListView with check box

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have a `ListView` with the `CheckBox`. I want to get the selected items from the `ListView` like example MyFiles application we selecting the multiple files with `CheckBox` and clicking the single delete button to delete all the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  boolean bulkflag = false;
  ListView reportslistview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    //private List<Table> tables;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    private Activity activity;
    String val = "";

    //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> tables, int resource, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, tables, resource, from, to);
        //this.tables = (List<Table>) tables;
        activity    =   context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (row == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reports_list, null);
        }       

        final CheckBox cBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        if(bulkflag)
        {
            cBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            cBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(cBox.isChecked())
                {
                    selectedIds.add(recIdArr.get(reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox)));
                    //System.out.println("position "+reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox));
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedIds.remove(recIdArr.get(reportslistview.getPositionForView(cBox)));
                }
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
}
```

Checking ====>

```
 for(int i=0;i<selectedIds.size();i++)
 {
    System.out.println("delete multiple"+selectedIds.size()+" "+Integer.parseInt(selectedIds.get(i)));
 }
```

Declare `selectedIds` as a global variable

Comment: where should i declare this array "recIdArr"?

Comment: its a arraylist where the list of items to be added to the list view

Comment: @Ramkiran can you please explain what is reportslistview and bulkflag ?

Comment: @Ramkiran
int pos= listview.getPositionForView(cBox); gives a null pointer exception ... what it is that might be causing the problem here??I have initialized the listview as you have mentioned in the edit!

Comment: have you declared the cbox as CheckBox cBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cb1);

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple solution which works for me:

Like this you can iterate through the ListView by using the already extisting ArrayList for the ArrayAdapter.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayList.size();i++){

if((CheckBox)listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox) != null){

    CheckBox cBox=(CheckBox)listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    if(cBox.isChecked()){
        Log.e("CB", ""+i);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a OnClickListener to your checkboxes ( in your adapter ). This listener will have to keep up to date a list with the file you want to delete when the button is pressed.

Something like :

Checked => Add to the List
UnChecked => Remove from List

Answer (score 1):

```
Listview list;

ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,"Arraylist name");

list.setAdapter(aa);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
     //code 
   }
```